# Unit testing- Test Switch Case Without any function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have simple JavaScript file and not able to write the test cases using JEST ,React Testing Library - REACT JS. Below are the code:

```
const ENV_URL = window.location.origin; //'https://note-dev.meta.com'
const REGEX = /(-)\w+/;
let LINK_ENV = ENV_URL.match(REGEX) && ENV_URL.match(REGEX)[0];
 
switch (LINK_ENV) {
  case "-dev":
    LINK_ENV = LINK_ENV.concat('1');
    break;
  default:
    LINK_ENV = '-prd';
    break;
}
export const CONFIGSERVICE = {
  LINK: 'http://oppo' + LINK_ENV + '.internal.meta.com',
  
};
```

My test case is:

```
import {CONFIGSERVICE} from '../../config/development';
    test('success2', () => {
            const ENV_URL = 'https://note-dev.meta.com';
            const REGEX = /(-)\w+/;
            let LINK_ENV = ENV_URL.match(REGEX) && ENV_URL.match(REGEX)[0];

            switch (LINK_ENV) {
            case "-dev":
                LINK_ENV = LINK_ENV.concat('1');
                break;
            }
            expect(CONFIGSERVICE.LINK).toBe("http://oppo-dev1.internal.meta.com");
        })
```

[image]
Please help me out on this

Comment: Could you expand a bit more? Do you want to test out a function?

Comment: I have updated. Please check